# DATABASE_URL environment variable not found

Tags: docker-compose, prisma

I have the following in my docker compose yml file, but my node app with prisma can't access the DATABASE_URL environment variable.
I'm new to docker, do I have to manually set the url, if so whats the url ?

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=local
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "5438:5432"
```

Comment: Can you show me `.env` file in your node.js?

Comment: I don't have a .env, shouldn't docker compose automatically make one ?

Comment: have you search on this? [link](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-not-seeing-environment-variables-on-the-host/11837/11)

Comment: Actually NO, you have to create `.env` manually, then add `DATABASE_URL` variable to it.

Comment: so what would be the format for that  something like this ?
postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5438:5432/local

Comment: It should be something like `DATABASE_URL="postgresql://johndoe:randompassword@localhost:5432/mydb?schema=public"`

Comment: The host would probably be `postgres` instead of `localhost` as you are running prisma in a different container than postgres.